# How to prevent page reload after uploading file to dev server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload

I have a react application running on port 3000 and my dev server running on port 5000. I have a form (yes I have the buttons set to onClick events and not submit with preventDefault) which sends information to a remote API and a file to my dev server /upload.do and then to my public/images folder. The form was handling great until I added a file upload to server axios call and now it refreshes the entire page once file uploading occurs. I have researched this and it seems that this is caused by a change in the public folder which causes a page refresh. My server.js uses express-fileupload to handle api calls to localhost/5000/upload.do. Everything is working except it refreshes my page which I cannot have happen.

**My question is: how do I stop a page refresh from occurring when uploading a file to my public/images folder?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you probably have dev server on watch mode. so when you upload a file, the watcher detects somethign change on disk and reload.

find that option and turn it off.

alternatively, some watchers have option to ignore certain folder. you can add that images folder to ignore list.

you mentione react app so i think you may use webpack-dev-server?

to disable watch mode for certain files/folders, do like this

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'images') // image folder path
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's the solution i'm looking for. How do I change watch mode of dev server? or add images folder to ignore list?

Comment: can you post your `package.json` script section?

Comment: I fixed it by uploading my images to a file directory that was not being watched and created a public static folder for the images to have an endpoint with express. By letting me know about the watch file structures I was able to fix this myself thank you Tuan Anh Tran!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `e.preventDefault();`, it's use to stop default page reloading.
You can see this link, [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)!

Comment: Tried it, did not work. It's the file system changing that is causing it... not the form.