# Posting Form Data in Javascript with Fetch - Bug

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I'd like to start by mentioning that I'm using vanilla Javascript and PHP, no jquery.  The code that I have posted below is just a fragment.  I have not included the PHP file or other code in javascript.

Now, the problem I am having is that no other code besides the form data post runs whenever I click my save button and activate the event.  I have a console log at the beginning and end of the event to test if other code runs, and it never does.  The form data, in this case a picture, gets posted to the PHP rest API file and stored in a folder as it should, but I do not receive a response in JSON from the PHP file that it is posted to, and my biggest problem is that no other code besides the post request runs in the event of the javascript code.  Neither of the console.logs (test 1 and test 2) will appear.

When I test the post request with any other type of data, for instance, JSON, everything works perfectly.  All of the code in the event runs, and I can receive responses in JSON from the same PHP file that the request was made to.  There's something about posting form data that creates this bug.  I hope that I have explained this clearly enough.  Thank you for any assistance.

```
save_bg_btn.addEventListener('click', save_background_picture);

async function save_background_picture(){

    console.log("test 1");

    const formData = new FormData();
    const save_files_background_pic = file_bg_pic.files[0];
    const url = 'http://localhost/test/background-cover.php';

    formData.append("file_bg_pic", save_files_background_pic);

    await post_formdata_request(url, formData)
        .then(data =>{ 
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    
     console.log(test 2);

}


function post_formdata_request(url, formData){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this button is in a `form`, I think you need to add `preventDefault()` for the click event otherwise the form will submit and refresh the page. Also, fix the second `console.log` because that was breaking my tests until I noticed it as well.

```js
async function save_background_picture(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // ...rest of the code

    console.log("test 2");  // <--- needed quotes
}
```

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for your reply.  Yes, I needed to add quotes, but unfortunately this still doesn't solve the problem I've run into.  When posting form data using fetch, no other code will run within the event.  I've created some example files to show the problem.  I will post them as an answer in this thread.

Comment: I've figured out that the page is in fact refreshing whenever I post the FormData.  The problem is it refreshes even when using event.preventDefault().

Comment: So, you're getting the problem with the *exact* sample code you posted? I haven't tried the PHP side, but the JS seems to be working properly. In here, https://jsfiddle.net/myg5sowu/, the two log lines do run and the page doesn't refresh.

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting the problem. I clicked on the link you posted and test that code, and it worked exactly as I would expect the code to, but when I test the code in MS VS Code it does not work.  The page refreshes.  Weird.  Maybe there's something wrong with my IDE or even computer?

Comment: Is there any way you could test the code with the PHP file and see if you get any error?

Comment: Yeah, let me see if I can get something set up real quick.

Comment: I just noticed that when I physically delete the files that I add to the image folder, the page refreshes in the browser.  I believe that the actual addition of files to the folder is causing the page to refresh, and that there is nothing actually wrong with the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094849/how-to-prevent-page-reload-after-uploading-file-to-dev-server    The question is this thread is similar to the problem that I now believe I am having.  I am using PHP though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932233/how-to-avoid-move-uploaded-file-refresh-the-page-on-button-click  Found the answer in this thread.  I'm using Live Server and apparently Live Server causes an automatic page refresh whenever changes are made to the folder system.  I turned off live server and everything worked as it should.  I was able to post the file and see the console logs.  Thank you so much for your time and help.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Great! Yeah, I was just about to say, it was working for me and I wasn't sure how you were testing **in** VS code. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

html file: test-fetch.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="file" id="inpFile">
    </form>
</body>

<script>

    const inpFile = document.getElementById('inpFile');
    const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

    myForm.addEventListener('change', inpFunction);

    async function inpFunction(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const endpoint = "http://localhost/php-practice/test-fetch.php";
        const formData = new FormData();
        
        formData.append('inpFile', inpFile.files[0]);

        fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
</script>
</html>
```

And this is the php file: test-fetch.php

```
<?php

    $file = $_FILES['inpFile'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['inpFile']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['inpFile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['inpFile']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['inpFile']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['inpFile']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');
    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($fileError === 0){
            if($fileSize < 2000000){
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;

                $fileDestination = 'images/'.$fileNameNew;

                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            }else{
                echo "Your file is too large!";
            }
        }else{
            echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
        }
    }else{
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }

    echo 'Success';
?>
```

Now, if you add any other code, such as a console log inside the function "inpFunction" it will not run.  The only code that will run will be the fetch posting the form data to the php file.  This problem is really baffling me.

edit:  the php file requires a folder called "images" as that is the path destination of any pictures being posted.